# Elasticsearch Docker-Compose dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9200: connect: connection refused

Tags: docker, go, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I have got a Go and Elasticsearch task and I see an error that I don't understand. Normally, my code works without Docker.

This is my `compose.yml`

```yaml
version: '3.1'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.15.0
    container_name: elasticsearch
    ports:
      - 9201:9200
    environment:
      - discovery.type=single-node

  monolith:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM golang:1.22 AS build-env

WORKDIR /src
ENV CGO_ENABLED=0
COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN go build -a -o webpalm -trimpath
FROM scratch AS final
WORKDIR /
COPY --from=build-env /src/webpalm .
COPY --from=build-env /src/sample.json .

CMD ["./webpalm"]
```

[image]

My Go code:

```golang
for _, item := range items {
        req := esapi.IndexRequest{
            Index:      "sample_index",
            DocumentID: item.ID,
            Body:       bytes.NewReader(encodeJSON(item)),
            Refresh:    "true",
        }

        res, err := req.Do(context.Background(), es)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Data indexing error", err)
            return
        }
        defer res.Body.Close()
    }
```

Comment: Instead of incorrect use of `127.0.0.1` use your Docker service name `elasticsearch`.

Comment: have you tried adding both containers to the same network in the docker-compose.yml? https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that your Elasticsearch and your Go application don't share the `localhost` network. Instead, connect to Elasticsearch using the service name defined in `docker-compose.yml`. Change your Go application's Elasticsearch connection string from `127.0.0.1:9200` to `elasticsearch:9200`.

With this modification, your Go application would communicate with Elasticsearch through Docker's internal networking, using the service name as the hostname.